# Ejabberd no etc , sbin folder after sudo make install

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, rebar3

So after installing all the dependencies I followed the instructions given on ejabberd git repo , (installing/building it from source)

but after sudo make install
none of *this* happened .

- *sudo make install

  These commands will:
  Install the configuration files in /etc/ejabberd/

  Install ejabberd binary, header and runtime files in /lib/ejabberd/

  Install the administration script: /sbin/ejabberdctl

  Install ejabberd documentation in /share/doc/ejabberd/

  Create a spool directory: /var/lib/ejabberd/

  Create a directory for log files: /var/log/ejabberd/*
  *

and yet if I run sudo ejabberdctl start , it starts and I can access debug shell as well, but get access denied witout using sudo,

Note :
1. after successful make ,I am getting a warning : " WARN:  Missing plugins: [rebar3_hex] "
2. I am using rebar3 v3.6.1 , Erlang/OTP 21, ejabberd v18
3. there is no etc folder, so no logs as well,
4. I can use sudo ejabberdctl start from anywhere in terminal,

Comment: They're all in /usr/local/etc/ejabberd, /usr/local/var/log/ejabberd, /usr/local/lib/ etc

Comment: The documentation may be wrong. But the paths shown when you run "make install" should be right. On the other hand, if you want to be able to run ejabberdctl with your user, not root, then use this: "./configure --enable-user"